# Windows 8. Metro application. XAML async binding

Tags: xaml, binding, asynchronous, microsoft-metro

The problem is with binding long time operation getter to UI control.
For example if I have a property like:

```
public string ButtonText
{
    get
    {
        Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
        return _buttonText;
    }
    set
    {
        _buttonText = value;
    }
}
```

and bind it in XAML to UI control like: `Content="{Binding ButtonText}"` the UI thread will be  blocked. There is a `Binding.IsAsync` property in WPF which allows to load binded data in background, but there is no such property in Metro framework.

Does anyone have any ideas about how can I make async bindings in metro application?

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft purposefully changed a bunch of things like this to encourage you to not do things in your property getters/setters that would need you to get the property async.  The "new" way to not block the UI thread is to do something like `await Task.Delay(3000)` instead of using `Binding.IsAsync`.  `await` blocks execution, but not the thread (exactly what you're trying to do).

Here is the page for more info about the `await` keyword in C# on .NET 4.5.  The example down at the bottom of the page gives a good idea of what your code should look like.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx

Comment: But how I can call await inside of property?